# Ethernet cable isn't being detected in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: internet, ethernet

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 smoothly. but for updation etc when I want to connect with my wired cable internet connection, find that all are same like the previous version and I put all ip address, dns etc properly and find the SAVE button was vanished!

I use Ubuntu for 7 years, but this the first time again I have to install the old version 11.10. Please advice. I installed it two times and same thing happen. now-a-days I use the previous version. Looking for a step by step tutorial where save button will not be vanished when I put my dns. My cable is working properly in windows 7 from where I send the mail.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with my notebook and Precise Pangolin amd64 installed, I had to use the switch in the control panel, network section, to enable the ethernet/LAN.